# change colour of cell if cell value is coppied in excel

Tags: excel

I want cell in "AS" color to be changed in cell value is copied i.e. on press on cntrl+c cell colour should get chnaged.
can anyone help to edit my below macro?

```
Sub ccopy()
    Dim x As Integer

    x = Selection.Column
    'MsgBox x

    If x = 45 Then
        With Selection
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End With
    End If

    'MsgBox "copy"

    Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is perfect. Its just I forgot to put triger to run it. ;-)